# merge TWO results of SQL select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

There are two types of data in the same mysql table.

Some data's specific column is set to '1' and another data's column is set to '0' (0 and 1 in the same column)

How can I mix them at once like below? (with select query) - every six '0' row is followed by one '1' row.

[image: my data]

Comment: There are about 40 columns. The name of specific column mentioned above is "wr_1". It is 1 or 0. And I want select them with no row missed,

Comment: Why does data8 appear twice? Why does first block in result set only have 5 0s? What happened to data7?And please add sample data and expected result as text to the question.

Comment: Sorry for duplicated data. I just want to get data. 00000010000001 like this manner

Comment: I think your looking for UNION. With this you can write 2 queries (same number/type of columns) and get the results together

Comment: Yes, I think the UNION doesn't matter now. I want get them with SELECT

Comment: 'There are about 40 columns' give an example with 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use window functions for sorting - if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select code, val
from mytable
order by
    row_number() over(partition by val order by code) 
        * (case when val = 0 then 1 else 5 end),
    val,
    code
```

The logic is to rank records having the same value ; then simple artithmetics can be used to handle the alternation (5 `0`s, then 1 `1`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=766e94641ba6af0e711f7ae906dfffca)**:

```
code   | val
:----- | --:
data1  |   0
data10 |   0
data11 |   0
data12 |   0
data13 |   0
data2  |   1
data14 |   0
data15 |   0
data3  |   0
data4  |   0
data5  |   0
data8  |   1
data6  |   0
data7  |   0
data9  |   0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but mysql version is 5.x and the number of columns are about 40. Will this can be problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as:

```
order by ( floor(row_number() over (partition by column order by data) - 1) /
                 (case when column = 1 then 1 else 5 end)
                )
         ),
         column,
         data
```

Comment: I can't list up the whole columns, but there are about 40 columns and I want them to be include in result

Comment: @SangjunNa . . . . This is only the `order by`.  You can use `select t.* from t` above this -- or any other query.

Comment: thank you but still in (mysql)version problem...mine doesn't support "over" function. Is there way ?